# Increase label width to the left side Titanium

Tags: ios, width, label, titanium

I have created a label and I would like to increase the width towards the left side instead of the default right side. And I don't want to move the label from its current position but only increase its width towards the left.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set fixed right margin :

```
Titanium.UI.createLabel ({
    width: 70,
    height: 40,
    right: 30, //your value
     //....
});
```

And then if you increase you label's width it will stretch only to the left side.